# Trying to hide thumbnails with pagination using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add pagination to the bottom of the page which allows the user to move from a group of thumbnail images to another. The page is a gallery page that the user can click the thumbnails on the left to change the slideshow on the right.

***HTML***

```
<div class="container">
<div id="main_area">
    <!-- Slider -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="slider-thumbs firstpage">
            <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
            <ul class="hide-bullets">
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1" id="carousel-selector-0">
                        <img src="images/thumbnails/img1.jpg">
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="images/thumbnails/img2.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="images/thumbnails/img3.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="images/thumbnails/img4.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="images/thumbnails/img5.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-5"><img src="images/thumbnails/img6.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-6"><img src="images/thumbnails/img7.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-7"><img src="images/thumbnails/img8.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-8"><img src="images/thumbnails/img9.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-9"><img src="images/thumbnails/img10.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-10"><img src="images/thumbnails/img11.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-11"><img src="images/thumbnails/img12.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-12"><img src="images/thumbnails/img13.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-13"><img src="images/thumbnails/img14.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-14"><img src="images/thumbnails/img15.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-15"><img src="images/thumbnails/img16.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-16"><img src="images/thumbnails/img17.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-17"><img src="images/thumbnails/img18.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-18"><img src="images/thumbnails/img19.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-1"  id="carousel-selector-19"><img src="images/thumbnails/img20.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="thumbnail page-2 hide-thumbnail"  id="carousel-selector-20"><img src="images/thumbnails/img21.jpg"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <nav>
              <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                  <a aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="pag-1">1</a></li>
                <li><a id="pag-1">2</a></li>
                <li><a id="pag-3">3</a></li>
                <li><a id="pag-4">4</a></li>
                <li><a id="pag-5">5</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="slider">
                <!-- Top part of the slider -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                            <!-- Carousel items -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                    <img src="images/img1.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                                    <img src="images/img2.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                    <img src="images/img3.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                    <img src="images/img4.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                    <img src="images/img5.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                                    <img src="images/img6.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="6">
                                    <img src="images/img7.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="7">
                                    <img src="images/img8.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="8">
                                    <img src="images/img9.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="9">
                                    <img src="images/img10.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="10">
                                    <img src="images/img11.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="11">
                                    <img src="images/img12.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="12">
                                    <img src="images/img13.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="13">
                                    <img src="images/img14.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="14">
                                    <img src="images/img15.jpg"></div>

                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="15">
                                    <img src="images/img16.jpg"></div>
                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="16">
                                    <img src="images/img17.jpg"></div>
                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="17">
                                    <img src="images/img18.jpg"></div>
                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="18">
                                    <img src="images/img19.jpg"></div>
                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="19">
                                    <img src="images/img20.jpg"></div>
                                <div class="item" data-slide-number="20">
                                    <img src="images/img21.jpg"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Carousel nav -->
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/Slider-->
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.hide-thumbnail{
  display: none;
}

.show-thumbnail{
  display: block;
}
```

***Jquery***

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                interval: 5000
        });

        //Handles the carousel thumbnails
        $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click(function () {
        var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
        try {
            var id = /-(\d+)$/.exec(id_selector)[1];
            console.log(id_selector, id);
            jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel(parseInt(id));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Regex failed!', e);
        }
    });
        // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
        $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
                 var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
                $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
        });
});

function ThumbnailPagination(){
  jQuery('#pag-1').live("click", function(){
        jQuery('.page-1').removeClass("hide-thumbnail");
        jQuery('.page-1').addClass("show-thumbnail");
  });
  jQuery('#pag-2').live("click", function(){
        jQuery('.page-1').removeClass("show-thumbnail");
        jQuery('.page-1').addClass("hide-thumbnail");
        jQuery('.page-2').removeClass("hide-thumbnail");
        jQuery('.page-2').addClass("show-thumbnail");
  });
};

</script>
```

I'm basically trying to hide/show the thumbnails when each `<a>` pagination number is clicked. However it normally only works once, and sometimes doesn't even work at all. Currently only "1" works, "2" doesn't even do anything.

LINK to website [Website Link](http://houstongreekfest.com/gallery1.php)

Comment: Where do you call `ThumbnailPagination`? Also, don't use `live`, use, `on`. `live` is removed from later versions of jquery.

Comment: i guess im never calling the function :o where should i call it?

Comment: In `jQuery(document).ready` callback function.

Comment: @Charles as @Molda says, call it inside the `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ });` I think before you call carosel is good enough. Unless carosel is key to the pagination somehow, in which case, best to call it after. Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem here was the solution

***HTML***

```
<nav>
              <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                  <a aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="pag-1">1</a></li>
                <li><a id="pag-2">2</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
```

***JQuery***

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pag-1').on("click", ThumbnailPagination1);
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pag-2').on("click", ThumbnailPagination2);
});

function ThumbnailPagination1(){
    jQuery('.page-1').removeClass("hide-thumbnail");
    jQuery('.page-1').addClass("show-thumbnail");
    jQuery('.page-2').removeClass("show-thumbnail");
    jQuery('.page-2').addClass("hide-thumbnail");
  };

function ThumbnailPagination2(){
    jQuery('.page-1').removeClass("show-thumbnail");
    jQuery('.page-1').addClass("hide-thumbnail");
    jQuery('.page-2').removeClass("hide-thumbnail");
    jQuery('.page-2').addClass("show-thumbnail");
  };
```

Comment: nice one. you don't have to have multiple `$(document).ready(function(){})` function calls though. It's much cleaner to keep it in just the one.